# How to align form in the same line with the other element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have elements in the footer of my card, and lastly I have a form. However, this form is put at the bottom of the other elements whereas I want it to be to the right of the last element (I'm using bootstrap). Here is a working example:

```css
        .css123 {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

        .css123:hover {
            color: #3DB9C3 !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card bg-light">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>
                            test
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer ">
                            <div class="float-start ">
                                <div class="text-start">
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        <small class="text-muted ">
                                            <a class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted mt-2 me-1">Test1</a>
                                            <a class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted mt-2 me-1">Test2</a>
                                            <a class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted mt-2 me-1">Test3</a>
                                            <form action="#" id="form-js">
                                                <a id="count-js"
                                                   class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted me-1">123
                                                    Like(s)</a>
                                                <input type="hidden" id="post-id-js">
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted me-1">
                                                    Like
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </small>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your markup to remove the form from the paragraph, then remove the `div.float-start` and `div.text-start` wrappers (they have no affect). Next add `.d-flex` to the `div.card-footer`. In the example below, I also added `.ms-auto` to the form to make it right-aligned (remove the class to have everything "float" to the left).

```css
.css123 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.css123:hover {
  color: #3DB9C3 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card bg-light">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>
              test
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer d-flex">

            <p class="card-text">
              <small class="text-muted ">
                                            <a class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted mt-2 me-1">Test1</a>
                                            <a class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted mt-2 me-1">Test2</a>
                                            <a class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted mt-2 me-1">Test3</a>
                                            </small>
            </p>
            <form action="#" id="form-js" class="ms-auto">
              <small>
              <a id="count-js" class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted me-1">123
                                                    Like(s)</a>
              <input type="hidden" id="post-id-js">
              <button type="submit" class="card-subtitle css123 text-muted me-1">
                                                    Like
                                                </button>
                                                </small>
            </form>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```